# PCB Silkscreen Marking

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, pc

Today, I came on a PC board and the silkscreen marking have TG on it. What is the component for TG?
[image]

Comment: Do you have a photo? That's not a very common one. Are you sure it's a designator and not the PCB material spec?

Comment: Is the TG marking followed by a number?  Possibly a European designation for a Gas Discharge Tube (GT vs. TG).  If used alone it might even designate that the PCB is made of a high temperature material, (The TG specification for a PCB is related to the "glass transition temperature" of the actual PCB material.)